# How to sign android apk without android studio

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk, ionic2

I have found **many many** confusing answers on this one: How do I sign (release/debug) android app **without Android Studio** (E.g. when signing ionic/cordova/phonegap app)?

Answer (score 3):

So, the right and simple answer *to date* is:

1. cd into your project platform/android folder (might just be your main project folder if not cordova/ionic build). You should find your main build.gradle file in that folder.
2. Create a keystore file by calling:

   ```
    keytool -genkey -v -keystore <KEYSTORE_FILE_NAME>.keystore -alias <ALIAS_NAME> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
   ```

Follow along and fill in <ALIAS_NAME> and passwords (write them down in a place you'll find them!)

3. Create two files named: `debug-signing.properties` and `release-signing.properties`
4. Enter the following configuration to both (you can later change the keystore to harden the security for release build...):

   ```
    keyAlias=ALIAS_NAME
    keyPassword=ALIAS_PASSWORD
    storeFile=KEYSTORE_FILE_NAME
    storePassword=KEYSTORE_PASSWORD`
   ```
5. Run build ...

Comment: The above command is documented in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#sign_cmdline.

Answer (score 3):

You can Add Key store in Gradle file.

```
 android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

--> use CMD for generate signed APK.

```
gradlew assemblerelease.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic team giving a great idea about this query you can follow this link and you can do this with in 10 min's

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

But You need **android sdk** to do this ...

To set ANDROID_HOME

Windows

```
set ANDROID_HOME=Path to sdk
```

Linux Based Systems

```
export ANDROID_HOME=Path to sdk
```

Steps to Follow

1. Create release app
2. Create keystore
3. Signing the APK

Comment: The thing is to get clear idea about it , So that i have added this answer , Before Signing the 
APK , Some plugins need to be removed ,Those things should not be avoided  ...

Comment: Sure, you also want to set the path to include the platforms and tools folder of the sdk... There are many prequisites, but how to set the keystore right was the missing part

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The easiest solution is to come back to the fundamentals through the DOS commands keytool and jarsigner. Note that these files must be located in the jdk directory to work well.

Only two actions to do:
- to use keytool for creating your keystore and your certificate(s):the first certificate is created when you create the single keystore. Then, the other certificates will be created by calling again the keytool command with the **same** keystore name
- then to use jarsigner. Prefer to **differentiate** the jar input filename and the generated **signed** jar filename when you prepare your jarsigner command