# Make APK without Android Studio

Tags: android

I need to generate a signed APK without Android Studio. Is there a way like a .exe program, a command in the cmd or a online service to do this?
I've to edit a JSON file inside the resource folder of the project and build the APK that I have to load on my device and I can't use Android Studio every time.

I can't use ionic, cordova or phonegap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sign android apk without android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244762/how-to-sign-android-apk-without-android-studio)

Comment: It isn't the same thing, i can't use ionic, cordova or phonegap. I need a .exe program, a cmd command ora an online service.

Comment: Yes but check @MIkka Marmik's answer `gradlew assemblerelease` is CMD command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute all the build tasks available to your Android project using the Gradle wrapper command line tool. It's available as a batch file for Windows (gradlew.bat) and a shell script for Linux and Mac (gradlew.sh), and it's accessible from the root of each project you create with Android Studio.

Find more here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official docs - [Build your app from the commandline](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline).

You can use gradle commands depending on which variant you want. For example,  `./gradlew installDebug` will make a debug apk and load it onto a connected device (though it won't open it like Android Studio does). `gradlew` is the Gradle wrapper file present in the root of the project.